# How can I except the style folder from the Authorization

Tags: asp.net, web-config, coding-style

My website is open only for authorized users, so I denied the anonymous users. but the problem is the style is corrupted because it's not allowed to anonymous users to access to the Style folder.

How can I except the style folder from the Authorization ?

```
<authorization>
   <deny users="?"/>
   <allow users="*"/>
</authorization>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the location element [as described here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b6x6shw7%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)

```
     <location path="style">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="*" />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
```